# how to call data from collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

[image]

this code I call the collection but I want call all data from the collection

```
export class RepairService {
    Reqref: AngularFirestoreCollection < ServiceRepair > ;
    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, public ngFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        this.Reqref = db.collection('iygR4pP0ZDXxBlFmzUMxAeqKtkt1', ref => ref.where("Title", "==", "Service & Repair"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load all data from the collection, remove the query from the `collection` call:

```
this.Reqref = db.collection('iygR4pP0ZDXxBlFmzUMxAeqKtkt1');
```

Or:

```
this.Reqref = db.collection('iygR4pP0ZDXxBlFmzUMxAeqKtkt1', ref => ref);
```

Comment: so if I want call data from another id I must get the id right?

Comment: or I need to declare name for the collection